# Using 'FileLen' with a four digit file extension

Tags: vba

I am working on a routine that gets the filelength for each of a large number of image files. When the routine runs file length against most files it works perfectly but some of the images have the file extension '.jpeg' and the FileLen command produces a 'File not found' error for these files. The code line I'm using is:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = FileLen(D & N)
```

Where D is a text variable containing the Drive Letter and N is a text variable containing the path and filename.

I have tested the string variables and they are supplying the correct full path and filename to the FileLen command. I have also set up a test routine to check with other files and this produces the same result. Am I correct in assuming that FileLen does not work with 4 digit file extensions? Is there a simple way round the issue?

The routine will be checking and comparing around 240,000 files with a fair proportion being .jpeg so going in and changing the extensions isn't an option.

Rob

Comment: No, it should work for them all. Is it located in mypictures and giving a path something like ```Libraries\Pictures\``` where the actual path is more like ```C:\Users\username\Pictures```

Comment: Can you try to set the `FileLen` to a variable and see if it works? If you have 240k files means you are offsetting 2 * 240k, since you are offsetting columns... the max columns for a sheet is 16384. That could be the error.

Answer (score 1):

`FileLen` can handle extensions with more than 3 characters, so that's not your problem.

Assuming that your values for `D` and `N` are correct (you should consider to use more meaningful names for your variables), I can imagine that it *may* be confused because of interference between short and long name of a file, but I cannot prove this.

You could try to use the `FileSystemObject` as alternative. Add a reference to the scripting runtime and use:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso As FileSystemObject

Function getFSO() As FileSystemObject
    ' Create object only if neccessary
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set getFSO = fso
End Function

Function getFilesize(filename As String) As Long
    ' Return the size of a file or -1 if not found or any error 
    getFilesize = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    getFilesize = getFSO.GetFile(filename).Size
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Usage:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=2).Value = getFilesize(D & N)
```

Comment: Thomas, doesn't the problem stays the same? If he is checking 240k files and throwing the results into columns, offseting 2 at a time will eventually max the limit of columns for a sheet. Right?

Comment: In the post, OP just mention offset from the `activeCell`, I don't think that this walks from left to right, probably from top to bottom. I don't think that this is the problem, the error would be different (1004).